# Freeze at full screen under XFCE (Ubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, video, xfce

in Ubuntu 17.04 under XFCE my laptop would just suddenly freeze when toggling to full screen mode when watching videos on YouTube. It doesn't necessarily freeze immediately but ranges from immediate to a couple of seconds. Under a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 however it doesn't. I have actually tried Xubuntu first and discovered this problem and hoped that Ubuntu under XFCE would be an option for me, however after installing XFCE Ubuntu would behave the same, even after doing a purge uninstall of XFCE, Ubuntu would no longer play videos on full screen without freezing. The only way to recover that I know of so far is to force shutdown the laptop because neither key combinations nor mouse do anything. I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu again to get YouTube videos playing properly on full screen again.

I can't actually hear audio since I'm actually trying to get a distro to run on this laptop. I managed to get WiFi, power indicator and bluetooth to work with just the audio and SD card slot left then I discovered this problem..

I tried Ubuntu Gnome, it would hold for a couple of attempts, however, spamming the full screen toggle reveals it has the same problem. I also tried Linux Mint Mate, and Linux Mint Cinnamon and they are the same. Tried Elementary OS but it wouldn't even boot past the logo.. Deepin OS can hold off but the video playback is sluggish so I gave up on it..

**TL; DR**

Ubuntu 17.04 would work fine with playing YouTube videos on full screen but not when under XFCE and neither after purging XFCE afterwards. Force shutdown is my only way to recover.

This laptop is from an unknown brand actually so I don't think it would help.. It has an Intel Atom x5-Z8350 Cherry Trail CPU. I never really knew Atom devices aren't well supported (at least not yet) under Linux until now so my bad for that, however I do hope someone could help.. Thank you.

Comment: "Z" and "X" series are notoriously unsupported. Forget about the audio, it's hopeless. Workaround: A generic USB audio card should work.

Comment: That's too bad.. I've always liked playing around low powered devices because then I would know that my software would run on minimal requirements and I really really like that for some strange reason.